# Count posts by tags even for tags that have not posts

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

In Entity Framework Core I have 3 entities:

```
public class Post { 
  public Int32 PostId { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; } 
}

public class PostTag { 
  public Int32 PostId { get; set; } 
  public Int32 TagId { get; set; } 
  public virtual Post { get; set; }
  public virtual Tag { get; set; }
}

public class Tag { 
  public Int32 TagId { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; } 
}
```

I need to get the Post Count per Tag so I tried:

```
IQueryable<PostTag> postTags = context.PostTags.AsNoTracking();

var stats = await postTags
  .GroupBy(x => x.Tag)
  .Select(x => new {
    TagId = x.Key.Id,
    TagName = x.Key.Name
    PostCount = x.Count()
  }).ToListAsync();
```

The problem is that Tags with not posts to not appear ...

And I would like them to appear with PostCount = 0.

How can I do this?

Comment: That worked. If you add your code as an answer I can mark it as the Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem as I see it is that you are starting from `PostTags`, and presumably there aren't any records in `PostTags` in this case; it seems like you want to start from `Tags`, then *left-outer* through to `Posts`. Actually: assuming you have referential integrity, you shouldn't even need to get to `Posts` - `PostTags` should be enough. So... perhaps just:

```
await context.Tags.AsNoTracking().Select(x => {
   x.TagId, PostCount = x.PostTags.Count() }).ToListAsync();
```

(sorry if the LINQ is rusty - - personally I'd just write it as SQL, so I know *exactly* what SQL is being executed)